# SUPEE-11086 Patch for Magento CE 1.9.3.9

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-11086, magento-1.9.3.9

as my question says, I need to know if there is the released of Magento Patch SUPEE-11086 for M1 versione 1.9.3.9.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Please download and apply this patch `PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.3.10_v1.sh (0.06 MB)` which is applicable from Magento 1.9.2.5 to 1.9.3.10

Comment: I've tried in this way but it returns me this error: Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully... ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully. checking file app/Mage.php Hunk #1 succeeded at 808 (offset 3 lines). Hunk #1 FAILED at 57. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED Hunk #1 FAILED at 69. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED I can't report all error for characters limit.

Comment: So have you done any changes to the files mentioned in patch manually?

Comment: No sir, I haven't modify those files

Comment: It would be helpful if you copy and paste your file name and share the screenshot of the error you are getting while you are applying the patch

Comment: https://paste.pics/6d42d8ca5528d836bc29046c37e1be8c
You can see this screenshot. The Patch is the SUPEE-11086.

Comment: These are the two files which is causing issue. 

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php

Please check these files,You compare the files with fresh Magento files to see if any manual changes were done to those files. If you still face any problems I request you to backup the two files remove it and replace these two files with fresh Magento 1.9.3.10 and apply the patch.

Comment: Hi Raj, I've tried in this way but it return me error on file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php. 
This is the screenshot: https://paste.pics/c0cac6bb0a24d028e9c7809a2ba43c34

Comment: Please double check this file still some difference is there app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php

Comment: No, there is no difference between the file. I've also uploaded the file from 1.9.3.10 version but it returns me that error.

Comment: I can able to understand it, but if you have replaced the original file there is no possibility for this error to occur, since this works fine if files unaltered. I have applied this patch for Magento 1.9.3.9 and it applied successfully for me. So do you have any fresh version right, try applying the patch there even single space could cause error. Are you copying the file or content.

Comment: I'm copying the file, not the content.

Comment: So simply try applying the patch file in fresh instance no need to setup the fresh one just apply and check if the patch works fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is available in Archive Downloads of Magento Opensource. **Patch Release on March 26, 2018**.

```
PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.3.10_v1.sh (0.06 MB)
```

[magento.com/security/patches/supee-11086.](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-11086.)

Comment: I've tried in this way but it returns me this error:
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/Mage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 808 (offset 3 lines).

Hunk #1 FAILED at 57.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED

Hunk #1 FAILED at 69.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED

I can't report all error for characters limit.